# How to set the length of an array during runtime

Tags: arrays, go, data-structures

I have to basically set the length of an 2 dimension array depending of how many elements I found on a Json File, not sure how to do it. I already have a method who is going to read my Json File, however Im not sure how to set the length of my 2 dimension array after I finished to read it.

Comment: Are you unmarshaling the JSON file? If so, you don't need to pre-allocate.

Comment: An array is defined with a static size. You need a slice, and if you are unmarshaling json, that should be done for you.

Answer (score 0):

`json.Unmarshal` will allocate slices as needed. Go slices are what you probably mean by variable-sized arrays. Here's a simple example:

```
b := []byte(`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`)
var slice2d [][]int
if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &slice2d); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println("Unmarshaled", slice2d)
```

---

If you're reading into something else and not directly into a 2d slice, then perhaps you're just looking for `make`?

This will allocate a 2D slice, NxM:

```
twoD := make([][]int, N)
for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
  twoD[i] = make([]int, M)
}

// Now you can write into twoD[i][j], given i<N, j<M
// and no extra allocation will be incurred.
```

Comment: Thanks! That´s what I needed. I really appreciate it!